# XML and XSD (from a Word document)

Tags: xml, xsd, ms-word

At work we need to be able to create XML files that follow a XSD schema. The
information that would go into that XML file would come from a Word file.
How would I go about doing this programatically? I've been searching using
Google but all I could find were things like converting from XML to XSD or
viceversa. The final XML would be uploaded to a web site (thus the XSD we have
to follow coz they will validate our XML using that schema. We have the schema).
What do i need? A parser? A validation tool? A custom API?

Please help since I'm pretty new to XML (i know basic HTML). My programming
skills are C and C++.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Found out about Serialization. This would solve my problem. Trying to find out how it Works :)

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Word documents since Word 2007 are saved in a DOCX format that follows the [Office Open XML](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm) (OOXML) standard.  Start by reading this [Office Open XML Overview](http://www.ecma-international.org/news/TC45_current_work/OpenXML%20White%20Paper.pdf).  Knowing this, you'll then be able to construct some reasonable searches to find OOXML tutorials and code samples.

Be warned that this is not an easy first project in XML.  Your challenges will include having to map from an complicated layout and presentation based XML to your XML, which presumably is either structurally/semantically based or of a completely different presentation format.